# Comparing two Anagram methods

Tags: python, anagram

I have a simple Anagram problem in which i will be given a word and another list of words. In that list of words i have to find out which of them are anagrams of the first word.

So i checked the internet and came up with two solutions as described below :

Solution 1:

```
from collections import counter
def checkAnagram(word,words):
    anagrams = []
    for w in words:
        if len(w) != len(word):
            return False
        elif w == word:
            return False
        else:
            if counter(word) == counter(w):
                anagrams.append(word)
            else:
                return False
return anagrams
```

Solution 2:

```
def anagramSolution4(s1,s2):
    c1 = [0]*26
    c2 = [0]*26

    for i in range(len(s1)):
        pos = ord(s1[i])-ord('a')
        c1[pos] = c1[pos] + 1

    for i in range(len(s2)):
        pos = ord(s2[i])-ord('a')
        c2[pos] = c2[pos] + 1

    j = 0
    stillOK = True
    while j<26 and stillOK:
        if c1[j]!=c2[j]:
            return False

def checkAnagram(word,words):
    anagrams = []
    for w in words:
        if anagramSolution4(word,w):
            anagrams.append(w)
    return anagrams
```

My question both seem to be using O(nm) complexity right ? So here n is size of input words and m is the maximum size of a word.

Can someone point me if there is better solution which uses even less complexity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your first solution, I'm pretty sure you shouldn't have those `return False` lines. With that there, you just exit the function as soon as you get to a word that isn't an anagram. And you return a boolean instead of a list. You only return a list if all of the words are anagrams.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can decrease the time complexity, but you can definitely make efficiency gains by caching the results from `counter()`

Comment: `n` being the number of words, `m` the length of the test word, `p` the average length of a word in words, the first solution is `O(n*(m+p))` which you can get to `O(m+n*p)` by making the `Counter` for the test word once outside of the loop and reusing it.